# Comparing two or more values string in php

Tags: php

Can i check a data is exist on result data loop? and if it doesn't exist will be shown. for example,
i have a data on loop method like **1234**, **2345**, and **3456**. and i want to check anywhere the same with my data like **1234**, **9212**,  **3333**, and **2345**. and result must be..

"Found **1234**, **2345**. Not found number **9212**, **3333**"

anyone please can help me..
with a pleasure if there is someone to help me solve this problem :)

Thanks before.

Comment: Do you have some code that is not working or giving you any errors ? You could maybe try something like this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Use `array_intersect` to find the matching elements, `array_difference` to find the missing elements.

Comment: thanks @Barmar, its worked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not very clear, but based on your explanation, instead of a loop, you may want to just use the build `array_interssect` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

This will let you compare two arrays, and check what values on one array exsits in the other.
For ex.:

```
$exists = array_intersect([1234,2345,67879], [1234,2345,9434,6439]);
```

This will result in `$exist` being an array with with two items `[1234,2345]`. Then you know the rest doesn't exist.
I hope this helps.